# Reset Redux state in browser during debugging

Tags: redux, redux-persist

So I am debugging my redux app on the browser, I had a bug which modified my state and I am also using redux- persist, the state is persisted on my browser.

I wanna reset the state to be an empty slate again, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by using `localStorage.clear()` in browser's console.

Comment: The browser's integrated dev tools also allow to clear localStorage, sessionStorage, cookies etc. It can be bit more convenient to view and edit localStorage with those.